# how to choose the best fitting function for a data set

Tags: python, curve-fitting, function, computational-statistics

I am trying to find the best fitting function for some data. 
I have tried with :

```
my_model = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(arr_x, arr_y, 4))
plt.plot(arr_x, my_model(arr_x), 'g-')
```

where `arr_x` and `arr_y` are original data. This is what comes out:

[image: original (blue) and fitting function (green)]

The functions with the blue color are the original one and those in green are supposed to fit the blue functions.
These green functions remain the same, even if I increase the Polynom grad of the fitted function in `my_model = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(arr_x, arr_y, 4))` to a number higher than 4 
How could I compute functions to fit the original data (blue functions) ? 
Could I find appropriate function to well fit the data ? 
Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. 
These following data are for the function on the right (the blue function). It could help to make some test.

```
arr_x = [4641.00003052, 4641.09999084, 4641.19999695, 4641.30001831, 4641.40000916, 4641.50001526, 4641.59999084, 4641.70002747, 4641.80001831, 4641.8999939, 4642.00001526, 4642.10002136, 4642.19999695, 4642.29998779, 4642.3999939, 4642.50001526, 4642.60002136, 4642.70001221, 4642.79998779, 4642.8999939, 4643., 4643.10002136, 4643.20002747, 4643.30000305, 4643.40000916, 4643.50001526, 4643.6000061, 4643.69999695, 4643.80001831, 4643.8999939, 4644.00001526, 4644.09999084, 4644.20001221, 4644.30003357, 4644.40002441, 4644.5, 4644.6000061, 4644.69999695, 4644.80000305, 4644.8999939, 4645.00001526, 4645.10002136, 4645.20002747, 4645.30000305, 4645.40002441, 4645.50001526, 4645.59999084, 4645.69999695, 4645.80001831, 4645.90002441, 4646.00003052, 4646.1000061, 4646.20001221, 4646.30001831, 4646.40000916, 4646.5, 4646.60002136, 4646.70002747, 4646.80001831, 4646.90002441, 4647.00001526, 4647.1000061, 4647.20002747, 4647.30000305, 4647.40002441, 4647.5, 4647.6000061, 4647.69999695, 4647.80001831, 4647.8999939, 4648., 4648.10002136, 4648.20002747, 4648.30000305, 4648.3999939, 4648.50003052, 4648.6000061, 4648.70001221, 4648.80001831, 4648.90002441, 4649.00001526, 4649.1000061, 4649.20001221, 4649.29998779, 4649.40000916, 4649.50003052, 4649.59999084, 4649.69999695, 4649.80000305, 4649.90002441, 4650., 4650.10002136, 4650.20002747, 4650.30001831, 4650.3999939, 4650.50001526, 4650.6000061, 4650.69999695, 4650.80000305, 4650.90000916, 4651., 4651.10002136, 4651.19999695, 4651.30001831, 4651.3999939, 4651.5, 4651.59999084, 4651.69999695, 4651.80001831, 4651.8999939, 4652., 4652.10002136, 4652.19999695, 4652.30001831, 4652.40002441, 4652.50003052, 4652.6000061, 4652.70001221, 4652.80000305, 4652.90000916, 4653.00003052, 4653.10002136, 4653.19999695, 4653.30001831, 4653.40000916, 4653.50003052, 4653.6000061, 4653.70001221, 4653.80001831, 4653.90002441, 4654.00001526, 4654.09999084, 4654.20001221, 4654.30000305, 4654.3999939, 4654.50003052, 4654.6000061, 4654.70001221, 4654.80000305, 4654.90000916, 4655., 4655.09999084, 4655.20001221, 4655.30001831, 4655.40000916, 4655.5, 4655.60002136, 4655.70001221, 4655.80000305, 4655.90000916, 4656.00003052, 4656.09999084, 4656.20001221, 4656.30001831, 4656.40000916, 4656.5, 4656.60002136, 4656.70002747, 4656.80000305, 4656.8999939, 4657.00001526, 4657.1000061, 4657.19999695, 4657.30001831, 4657.3999939, 4657.5, 4657.60002136, 4657.70001221, 4657.80000305, 4657.90000916, 4658., 4658.10002136, 4658.19999695, 4658.30001831, 4658.40000916, 4658.50001526, 4658.59999084, 4658.69999695, 4658.79998779, 4658.90000916, 4659., 4659.1000061, 4659.20002747, 4659.29998779, 4659.40000916, 4659.5, 4659.6000061, 4659.70001221, 4659.80000305, 4659.90000916, 4660., 4660.1000061, 4660.19999695, 4660.30000305, 4660.40000916, 4660.5, 4660.6000061, 4660.70002747, 4660.80001831, 4660.90000916, 4661., 4661.10002136, 4661.20002747, 4661.29998779, 4661.3999939, 4661.50001526, 4661.60002136, 4661.70001221, 4661.80000305, 4661.90000916, 4662., 4662.09999084, 4662.19999695, 4662.30001831, 4662.40000916, 4662.50001526, 4662.60002136, 4662.69999695, 4662.80000305, 4662.8999939, 4663., 4663.1000061, 4663.19999695, 4663.30001831, 4663.40002441, 4663.50001526, 4663.60002136, 4663.69999695, 4663.80000305, 4663.90000916, 4664., 4664.1000061, 4664.20002747, 4664.30001831, 4664.40002441, 4664.50003052, 4664.6000061, 4664.70001221, 4664.80000305, 4664.90000916, 4665.00003052, 4665.10002136]

arr_y = [0.01210571, 0.01447399, 0.0101318, 0.01009226, 0.01006458, 0.01004521, 0.01003164, 0.01002215, 0.01301551, 0.01211085, 0.0144776, 0.01313432, 0.01219402, 0.01153582, 0.01107507, 0.01075255, 0.01052678, 0.01336875, 0.01235812, 0.01465069, 0.01325548, 0.01527884, 0.01369519, 0.01258663, 0.01181064, 0.01726745, 0.01508721, 0.01056105, 0.01039273, 0.01327491, 0.01229244, 0.00860471, 0.0120233, 0.01141631, 0.01399141, 0.00979399, 0.00985579, 0.00689906, 0.00482934, 0.00638054, 0.01046638, 0.01632646, 0.02042852, 0.02929997, 0.03250998, 0.03775698, 0.03242989, 0.02870092, 0.02609065, 0.02426345, 0.02598442, 0.02418909, 0.02893236, 0.02925265, 0.03247686, 0.0317338, 0.03421366, 0.03594956, 0.04316469, 0.05721529, 0.0730507, 0.09313549, 0.11619484, 0.14433639, 0.17303547, 0.19912483, 0.22938738, 0.25357117, 0.27049982, 0.28534987, 0.30174491, 0.31622144, 0.32935501, 0.3355485, 0.33988395, 0.35191877, 0.35734314, 0.3671402, 0.36499814, 0.3574987, 0.35824909, 0.35577436, 0.35104205, 0.35072944, 0.34751061, 0.35125742, 0.3538802, 0.34971614, 0.3408013, 0.32256091, 0.32479264, 0.32635484, 0.33344839, 0.34741387, 0.34818971, 0.3247328, 0.28731296, 0.24011907, 0.19208335, 0.14645834, 0.11752084, 0.10926459, 0.10948521, 0.10363965, 0.08454775, 0.05918343, 0.0444284, 0.02809988, -0.01033008, -0.04323106, -0.08726174, -0.13308322, -0.18615825, -0.24131078, -0.29791754, -0.34954228, -0.3736796, -0.37857572, -0.385003, -0.3955021, -0.40585147, -0.41009603, -0.40706722, -0.39894705, -0.39026294, -0.38418406, -0.38292884, -0.38505019, -0.38653513, -0.38757459, -0.38830221, -0.37981155, -0.37086809, -0.37060766, -0.37042536, -0.37329775, -0.37230843, -0.3746159, -0.37623113, -0.35636179, -0.31245325, -0.25771728, -0.21640209, -0.17548147, -0.12283703, -0.07698592, -0.04189014, -0.0173231, 0.00587383, 0.03411168, 0.05087818, 0.05661472, 0.06063031, 0.06344121, 0.06240885, 0.0676862, 0.06838034, 0.07486624, 0.08540636, 0.09578446, 0.10604912, 0.11323438, 0.10926407, 0.11248485, 0.11473939, 0.11031758, 0.1102223, 0.11015561, 0.11010893, 0.09507625, 0.06655337, 0.03158736, -0.01388885, -0.06072219, -0.09950553, -0.10565387, -0.09795771, -0.0805704, -0.06239928, -0.0526795, -0.04887565, -0.05521295, -0.05664907, -0.04865435, -0.04005804, -0.03404063, -0.03282844, -0.03197991, -0.03138594, -0.02797016, -0.01957911, -0.01370538, -0.01559376, -0.01691563, -0.01484094, -0.01038866, -0.00727206, -0.00509044, -0.00956331, -0.01269432, -0.00888602, -0.00622022, -0.00435415, -0.00304791, -0.00213353, -0.00149347, -0.00104543, -0.0007318, 0.00248774, 0.00174142, -0.00178101, -0.00124671, -0.00087269, -0.00361089, -0.00252762, -0.00176933, -0.00123853, -0.00086697, 0.00239312, 0.00167518, 0.00417263, 0.00292084, 0.00204459, 0.00143121, 0.00100185, 0.00070129, 0.00049091, 0.00334363, 0.00234054, 0.00163838, 0.00414687, 0.00290281, 0.00203196, 0.00142238, 0.00399566, 0.01179696, 0.02025787, 0.02618051, 0.03032636, 0.02722845, 0.02205992, 0.02444194]
```

Thank you.

Comment: An exponentially damped sum of sinusoids would probably fit it better. But you seem to have the period shortening. What does this data represent? Some additional context there could help determine what would be a good fit.

Comment: A $k$-degree polynomial has at most $k-1$ changes in direction (locations where the derivative goes from positive to negative or vice versa, i.e. zero derivatives). Your data appear to have more than 4 changes in direction, so 4 or less is a poor choice. There are lots of ways to create a more expressive basis, but which one is appropriate depends on your goals. What problem are you trying to solve, and how does estimating a high-degree polynomial solve it? As motivation, why is it not acceptable to just store the data and linearly interpolate between data points? This has great fit!

Comment: Hey @AdrianKeister , after reading your post I have added new functions. It is a mechanical system. These functions are robot's movements. Your are right, the function is always damped, either at the beginning or/and at the end.

Comment: What objective would be served by fitting *any* function to these data?

Comment: Polynomials never flatten out at the ends, and are hence not going to work well. I think I would echo whuber's comment: what do you gain by fitting a function to this data?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Sycorax whuber , Analysing functions (zeros, integral, derivatives) will help given appropriate conclusions

Comment: You have given me a new idea. I will try numerical integration. I don't need any fitted function for that.